# Bookshelf.js resuelve la Promesa pero no guarda en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, orm

Quiero saber por qué al usar Bookshelf.js la Promesa `save()` se resuelve, pero en realidad nada se guarda en la base de datos de PostgreSQL.

El código funcionaba correctamente, pero de repente dejo de hacerlo, estoy usando un servidor AWS con una instancia de Windows y lo primero que intente fue reiniciar el servidor, pero no funcionó.

La primera cosa que note después del reinicio, es que algunas variables de entorno de Windows desaparecieron, añadí las de los comandos de Node.js, NPM y PostgreSQL, pero el código sigue resolviendo la Promesa sin añadir realmente los registros.

En el ejemplo de abajo añadí funciones con el mismo patrón.... crean una instancia de un modelo de Bookshelf y lo guardan.

```
new Invoice(Info).save().then(model => {
  console.log('Saved Invoice');
  SaveAddOn(model.id, AddOnData);
  console.log('Line 546', model.id)
  SaveReceiver(model.id, ReceiverData);
  console.log('Line 548', model.id)
  SaveIssuer(model.id, IssuerData);
  console.log('Line 550', model.id)
  SaveConcepts(model.id, ConceptsData);
  console.log('Line 552', model.id)
  if(TaxesData!=null) {
    SaveTaxes(model.id, TaxesData, true);
    console.log('Line 555', model.id)
  }
  SaveRelatedInvoices(model.id, RelatedInvoicesData);
  console.log('Line 558', model.id)
  CheckStatus(model.id,re, rr, tt, id);
  console.log('Line 560', model.id)
  resolve(model.id);
})
```

Otra cosa, los `console.log()` dentro del `then()` no funcionan, no imprimen nada, pero cualquiera fuera de esta si lo hace...

Creo que este es un problema común con Bookshelf, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme en cómo afrontar este problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo esto paso por alguna dependencia dentro de **node_modules** que se debió romper después de instalar algún paquete.

Después de estar abrumado y frustrado, pensando en cómo resolver el problema, copie y combine un backup local de node_modules viejo que tenía en la carpeta actual, después de esto funcionó.

Sé que no es la manera más elegante de dar una solución pero no era un error con el código per se.